# SQLALCHEMY/FASTAPI/POSTGRESQL | Only retrieve double entries

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a database with a table named `friends`. That table has two columns, `"user_id" and "friend_id"`.
Those are foreign keys from the `Users` table.

My friends table right now:

```
               user_id               |              friend_id
-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------
 google-oauth2|11539665289********** | google-oauth2|11746442253**********
 google-oauth2|11746442253********** | google-oauth2|11539665289**********
 google-oauth2|11746442253********** | google-oauth2|11111111111**********
```

The first two rows are the same IDs but flipped. Those `Users` I want to retrieve, because they added eachother. The third row only added another guy, that one shouldn't be retrieved.

My SQLModels (models.py):

```
class Friends(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "friends"
    user_id: str = Field(sa_column=Column('user_id', VARCHAR(length=50), primary_key=True), foreign_key="users.id")
    friend_id: str = Field(sa_column=Column('friend_id', VARCHAR(length=50), primary_key=True), foreign_key="users.id")

class UserBase(SQLModel):
    id: str
    username: Optional[str]
    country_code: Optional[str]
    phone: Optional[str]
    picture: Optional[str]

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


class User(UserBase, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: str = Field(primary_key=True)
    username: Optional[str] = Field(sa_column=Column('username', VARCHAR(length=50), unique=True, default=None))
    phone: Optional[str] = Field(sa_column=Column('phone', VARCHAR(length=20), unique=True, default=None))
    picture: Optional[str] = Field(sa_column=Column('picture', VARCHAR(length=255), default=None))
```

My fastapi endpoint:

```
@router.get("", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, response_model=models.FriendsList, name="Get Friends for ID",
            tags=["friends"])
async def get_friends(
        user_id: str = Query(default=None, description="The user_id that you want to retrieve friends for"),
        session: Session = Depends(get_session)
):
    stm = select(models.User, models.Friends).where(models.User.id == models.Friends.friend_id, models.Friends.user_id == user_id)
    res = session.exec(stm).all()
    if not res:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                            detail="There are no friendships associated with this id.")
    users = []
    for item in res:
        users.append(item[0])
    return models.FriendsList(users=users)
```

My code works perfectly fine, only the query needs to be replaced.

```
stm = select(models.User, models.Friends).where(models.User.id == models.Friends.friend_id, models.Friends.user_id == user_id)
res = session.exec(stm).all()
```

This query returns every `User` that has the given ID as `user_id`, but doesn't check if there is an entry the other way around.

Example for what I want to get:

I make a GET request to my endpoint with the id `google-oauth2|11746442253**********`. I would get the User `google-oauth2|11539665289**********`. (The User `google-oauth2|11111111111**********` would not be retrieved because there is no entry the other way arround)

I hope you guys understand my problem. If there are any questions feel free to ask.

Best regards,
Colin

Comment: Have a look into relationships, you're making life hard by not using them. The `Friends` table should ideally be invisible and just allow you to query on `User.friends`. Also I'd suggest create a test database with data (and without fast API) to allow others to more easily test.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

are you able to add another column called "accepted" with values like 0 or 1?

```
           user_id                   |          friend_id                  | accepted
-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 google-oauth2|11539665289********** | google-oauth2|11746442253********** | 1
 google-oauth2|11746442253********** | google-oauth2|11539665289********** | 1
 google-oauth2|11746442253********** | google-oauth2|11111111111********** | 0
```

then you have two options:

1. you could make a relationship on the user table called "friends" and set the lazy parameter to "dynamic" (`lazy='dynamic'`) and then query: `user.friends.filter_by(accepted=1).all()`
2. or you could write a query like:

   `query = Friends.query.filter(Friends.user_id==user_id).filter(Friends.accepted == 1).all()`

generally relational databases aren't the best solution for these types of scenarios - if you're very flexible and not too far in you could checkout a NoSQL solution like MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, without a simple example I can't actually try myself, but I did just have an idea. You might need to modify the subquery syntax a little bit, but I reckon theoretically this could work:

```
stmt = select(Friends.user_id, Friends.friend_id).where(
    tuple_(Friends.user_id, Friends.friend_id).in_(select(Friends.friend_id, Friends.user_id)) 
)
```

Basically it's just checking every `(user_id, friend_id)` if there is a matching `(friend_id, user_id)`.